# Decide equality with some predicate

Tags: coq

I would like to prove that equality is decidable for those `a` that satisfy some predicate `P`:

```
Variable C: Type.
Inductive A: Type:=
    | A0: C -> A.
Variable P: A -> Prop.
Variable P_dec: forall a: A, {P a} + {~ P a}.

Definition A_dec: forall a b, {a = b} + {a <>  b} + {~ P a}.
```

But using `decide equality`, I lose the information that `a` satisfies `P`:

```
intros. destruct (P_dec a). left. decide equality.
```

I get

```
a, b: A
p: P a
c, c0: C
----------
{c = c0} + {c <> c0}
```

and I cannot use the fact that we have `P (A0 c)`. It seems to me that somehow I am legitimate to assume that `a = P c` - how can I proceed to get this information?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any hypothesis on `C`? For instance :

```
Variable Ceqdec : forall c c':C, {c = c'}+{c <> c'}.
```

Some types don't have this possibility (e.g; `C = nat->nat`)

About your other question :
You may start your proof with `intros [c] [c0]` in order to decompose `a`and `b`.